# Apache Kafka client with selector?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am investigating Apache Kafka, and my use-case requires that the client be able to filter messages, and that the filtering happens on the broker, rather than the client. This requirement is identical to using a JMS Selector.

It is my understanding, though I maybe incorrect, that Kafka does not have a selector, and that filtering is done on the client. So all messages are sent to client, and client is responsible for filter.

Is there anyway to achieve a JMS Selector approach, where filtering happens on the broker?

Comment: How did you end up implementing this? I'd love to hear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't do anything like that. The best you can do is filter on the client side. Apache Kafka API supports only fetching of kind "give me at most 1 megabyte of messages for topic N partition M starting from offset X".

You can refer to [Wire Protocol reference](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-FetchRequest) to see possible options for a fetch request, but it does not contain anything you are looking for.

Actually, Kafka is that fast because every fetch is just a sequential read, so I don't think this will be implemented in future releases (but I'll be glad if I'm wrong :)).

Answer (score 0):

You're right that filtering is done on the client-side.

Spring Cloud Stream provides an elegant way of implementing that with the support of dispatching messages to multiple handler methods annotated with `@StreamListener` based on conditions: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-stream-overview-producing-consuming-messages